# Cambiar de apariencia plantilla adminlte

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, css3, laravel-blade

**Diseñé un formulario tipo (perfil de  empresa)** donde se introduce el nombre de la empresa, logo, datos de contacto, etc **justamente este formulario tiene un campo que se llama color en el cual eligo un color a través de una paleta de colores todo se guarda perfecto.** Ahora lo que quiero hacer y **nose como hacerlo es que ese color elegido se refleje y modifique la apariencia de la plantilla adimlte cambiando de color  el header, nabvar y footer** como pasar los colores elegidos a la plantilla, precisamente al archivo app.blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el color de fondo de cualquier elemento añadiéndole un estilo directamente con jQuery. Solo tienes que situar el script en un *template Blade* que cargue en la página en cuestión.

Un ejemplo donde cambio el color de fondo de algunos elementos, con dos botones. Los colores los he prefijado y uso una forma diferente de aplicar el estilo para cada botón:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pruebas jQuery</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            text-align: center;
        }
        body {
            margin: 5% 12%;
        }
        button, footer, header, nav {
            border  : 1px solid grey;
            margin  : 1rem;
            padding : 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        This is the header
    </header>
    <nav>
        a nav
    </nav>
    <main>
        <button id="bg-grey">Set grey color</button>
        <button id="bg-pink">Set pink color</button>
    </main>

    <footer>
        The footer
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#bg-grey').click(function()
            {
                console.log('bg-grey');
                $('footer').css("background", "grey");
                $('header').css("background", "grey");
                $('nav').css("background", "grey");
            });
            $('#bg-pink').click(function()
            {
                console.log('bg-pink');
                $('footer').attr("style", "background:pink");
                $('header').attr("style", "background:pink");
                $('nav').attr("style", "background:pink");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```